# Connecting to Sqlalchemy database with PyQt and saving database contents into a TableView in PyQt

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyqt, psycopg2

I am currently working on an application that can access an sqlalchemy database using PyQt and displaying its contents into a TableView or some other widget. To keep it simple for now, lets just say that is a phonebook with a name, number, and street address. I would like to have the Tableview periodically update itself so if something is added to the database, it will refresh itself. connection to the database will also be done wirelessly, so I won't know if a change has been made. I have written some code that I modified from a postgrese database. But I have found poor documentation for the sqlalchemy aspect as well as for connecting with a engine driver in PyQt. Any help is appreciated or even a clear example. Thank you in advance.

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres::project@192.177.2.6:5432/masterdb')
```

The code above is just for creating the engine to connect to the sqlalchemy database

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not clear. It seems like you need more reading and practicing on SQLAlchemy and PyQt. SQLAlchemy is not a database, it is a SQL toolkit (also known as the core), and an ORM for a Python. It also has one of the best documentation I have seen for Python libraries, so not poor at all. PyQt is a binding for using Qt in Python. Both are different projects, and it is probable that you will have to write the logic by yourself to make the two libraries interact.

Comment: I'm still new to the project and trying to figure out some of the discrepencies on all of the applications we are using. I guess when I said poor documentation, I meant between interfacing with PyQt and Sqlalchemy. But essentially I am trying to connect the PyQt application using postgresql and psycopg2 with the sqlalchemy tooltkit. Im new to all of this and I have not been able to get too many details thus far.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is basically a millisecond refresh of the GUI contents which could be very straining on the server if the size of the data is huge and or if no of people accessing it is a lot. I would instead add a "refresh" push button that reloads the data from the database and puts it on to the qtablewidget when its clicked.

For connect through sqlalchemy to postgresql, I use this:

```
import sqlalchemy
User = "xxxx"
Pass = "xxxx"
Host = "192.168.x.x"
Port = "xxxx"
DB = "xxxx"
SQLEngine =   sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://'+User+':'+Pass+'@'+Host+':'+Port+'/' + DB,poolclass=sqlalchemy.pool.NullPool)
```

I use pandas to read the data from postgresql:

```
import pandas as pd
Data = pd.read_sql_query('select * from tablename ', con=SQLEngine)
```

Comment: This looks like a great start. I will keep you updated and I may have a follow up question. This is a large project, so we are trying to communicate with the right people on all of the questions we have regarding the GUI application using PyQt. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: Please feel free. I'm new to pyqt as well and I am working on a very similar project so we can help each other :-)